# Cascade doesn't work in Hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, cascade

I have a system in which I have two types of devices: Staticedevice and dynamicdevice. Since my knowledge of inheritance in mysql is limited, and I have no clue how to make it work with hibernate, I simply made a BASEDEVICE. So that both staticdevice and dyndevice have a foreignkey to a basedevice, and I've set the static and dyndevice nullable.

[image: The database]
The problem is, that when I save a basedeivce, I expect that either a dyndevice og a staticdevice is saved, since I've annotated it with CascadeType.Persist. It didn't work, so I tried using .ALL. Still doesn't work!

```
@Entity
@NamedQuery(name="Basedevice.findAll", query="SELECT b FROM Basedevice b")
public class Basedevice implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    //bi-directional one-to-one association to Dyndevice
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName="BASEDEVICE_id", nullable = true)
    private Dyndevice dyndevice;

    //bi-directional one-to-one association to Staticdevice
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName="BASEDEVICE_id", nullable = true)
    private Staticdevice staticdevice;

    //bi-directional one-to-one association to Devicemap
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName="BASEDEVICE_id", nullable = true)
    private Devicemap devicemap;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to Logentry
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="basedevice", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<Logentry> logentries;
    ....
}
```

Why doesn't it persist my static or dyndevice with it? The Basedevice is persisted fine, and I'm sure that it has a static device:

```
public void addStaticDevice(Staticdevice device) {
    DAO<Basedevice> basedeviceDAO = new DAO<>(Basedevice.class);
    basedeviceDAO.save(device.getBasedevice());
    devices_.add(device.getBasedevice());
}
```

where the .save method calls the entitymanager's persist-method. 
I've never had problems with cascade before.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does basedevice represent something, or you just need it to be some code unifing parent class? If you really need just staticdevice and dynamicdevice in your code and thus basedevice can be just a abstract parent (not a real entity) try making base device abstract, remove @ entity and use @ MappedSuperclass

Comment: @Nadir I like that idea. But then I would have to delete the Basedevice table, right? Or do I have to do something specific in my database, before I can do that?

Comment: Depends on the inheritance model you want to use, you can have a base table with common data and additional tables for specific fields, or one big table, or just 2 tables for entities (common fields will be in both tables). Depends on your needs, see http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbqn.html

Comment: It looks like you are walking down the wrong path. You should take a look at ```@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)```. It allows you to model the Entity hierarchy exactly like you would do in Java.

Comment: @KlausGroenbaek - I tried researhing the joined inhertiance type, and hell - it worked. Thank you.

Comment: Glad to help. JPA is fairly easy to get started with, but quite hard to master.   I started using it in 2010, and only googled when I ran it issues, so I learned mostly by doing (and debugging the EclipseLink code). In 2016 I had to teach a course in JPA and sat down and read the spec, and suddenly I understood all the problems I have had previously. Especially the differences between application and container managed Entitymanager (Persistence Context) and how it affects transaction scoping.